# cannot invoke '!=' with an argument list of type (@lvalue Bool, ($T5))

Tags: xcode, swift, nsstring, nsrange

The title is the error message that I get while compiling this code snippet @ line3:

```
var categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (candy.category == scope)
var stringMatch = candy.name.rangeOfString(searchText)
return categoryMatch && (stringMatch != nil);
```

Whats the problem here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `rangeOfString:` returns a `NSRange` that cannot be equatable to `nil`. Instead of that check the `location` property of `NSRange`.

You need to change your return statement like:

```
return categoryMatch && (stringMatch.location != NSNotFound)
```

References:

- [rangeOfString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:)
- [NSRange](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/tdef/NSRange)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the return type of the function isn't simply `Bool`.

`categoryMatch && (stringMatch != nil)` creates a Bool value.

Maybe your function return type is a tuple of `(Bool,Bool)`.
Then your correct return value should be something like

```
return (categoryMatch , (stringMatch != nil))
```